# shell command which returns the target of the static link

Tags: shell, command, ln

Is there a built-in unix/linux command which returns the target of a specific symbolic link?

for example if i made a symbolic link:

```
%> ln -s build_07-24-2011 latest
```

is there a command "foo" that does this:

```
%> foo latest
build_07-24-2011
```

i know that i can parse the `ll -l latest` with awk to get the same thing, just wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [readlink(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readlink).